# How to seperate login redirect urls in django

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I have built a django app.Can someone help me in seperating the redirect URLs while logging in from `facebook(django-social-auth)` and a normal login form.
I have two types of users, one which I need to login using facebook and the other using the form.
I have defined different URLs for both the purposes and defined it in my views.py
Also given `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in my settings.py, but when logging in using the form, it is also getting redirected to the same URL.
Please help.
Relevant code is attached
Thanks in advance.

views.py:

```
def admin_dashboard(request):
    if request.user.id!=None and request.user.usertype.description=="ADMIN" and request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method=="GET":
            return render_to_response('testu/admin_dashboard.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def student_dashboard(request):
    if request.user.id!=None and request.user.usertype.description=="STUDENT" and request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method=="GET":
            return render_to_response('testu/student_dashboard.html',{"tests":Test.objects.all()},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin_dashboard/',admin_dashboard),
    url(r'^student_dashboard/',student_dashboard),
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '...'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET = '...'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/student_dashboard/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/student_dashboard/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.customuser'
```

basically, whenever im signing in with user of "ADMIN" description, even that is being redirected to 'student_dashboard'

Comment: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/logged-in/'` ... not working ?

Comment: there are two types of users, t1 and t2. t1 can log in using either facebook or login form, and t2 can login using login form only.There's an attribute to the user which predermines the usertype. Need to redirect them to different urls accordingly, using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/logged-in/' only solved a handful of cases. earlier they were being redirected from views.py only, started facing this problem when used social auth logins

Comment: Can you show code you're using in your **views.py** and **urls.py** ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try having a common login Redirect view. Ex:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/my_common_view/'

def my_common_view(request):
    if user is student:
        redirect to student dashboard
    else:
        redirect to admin dashboard
```

This should solve this problem.